# Show or hide table rows based on text value in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I have table like:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" id="search" @bind-value="@search" />

<table class="table table-striped table-borderless">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Column 1 <span class="oi oi-file"></span></th>
            <th scope="col">Column 2 <span class="oi oi-file"></span></th>
            <th scope="col">Column 3 <span class="oi oi-file"></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            foreach (var row in list)
            {
                <tr class="@row.VisibilityCss">
                    <td>@row.Title</td>
                    ...
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Blazor code:

```
@code{
    private string _search = string.Empty;
    private string search
    {
        get
        {
            return _search;
        }
        set
        {
            _search = value;
            OnSearch(value);
        }
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<MyItem> list = new MyItem[]
    {
      new MyItem{ Title = "Salary", ... },
      new MyItem{ Title = "Bonus", ... }
    };
    
    private void OnSearch(string str)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var vs = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) || !item.Title.StartsWith(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            item.Visible = vs;
        }
    }
}
```

and the `MyItem` class:

```
public sealed MyItem 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; } = true;
    public string VisibilityCss => Visible ? "" : "hidden";
}
```

How to reflect changes to UI when I type words in search bar ?
I assigned the value to `Visible` property but does not reflects to UI, something is needed to do that but I don't know.

Any help ?

Comment: `var row in list.Where(a => a.Visible)`

Comment: I'm really stupid, didn't think about that very and extremely simple thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the list with a `linq` `Where` clause.

```
@foreach (var row in list.Where(a => a.Visible))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter on you list, list is bind to table UI, so whenever list is filtered the UI will change accordingly, as you type in input the list is filtered accordingly, Here is the solution

This should be your HTML

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" id="search" value="@search" @oninput=@(e=> OnSearch(e.Value.ToString())) />

    <table class="table table-striped table-borderless">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Column 1 <span class="oi oi-file"></span></th>
                <th scope="col">Column 2 <span class="oi oi-file"></span></th>
                <th scope="col">Column 3 <span class="oi oi-file"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                foreach (var row in filteredList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@row.Title</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And this the C# code

```
@code {

    private string _search = string.Empty;
    private IEnumerable<MyItem> filteredList;

    private string search
    {
        get
        {
            return _search;
        }
        set
        {
            _search = value;
            OnSearch(value);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<MyItem> list = new MyItem[]
    {
        new MyItem{ Title = "Salary"},
        new MyItem{ Title = "Bonus"}
    };


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        filteredList = list;
    }
    
    private void OnSearch(string str)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            filteredList = list;
        }
        else
        {
            filteredList = list.Where(x => x.Title.StartsWith(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        }
    }
    
    public sealed class MyItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }    
}
```